# Find out crash from OBD (On Board Diagnostic) data?

Tags: obd-ii

In our application we are collecting OBD data continuously from vehicles port. Our requirement is to find out the vehicle crash scenario (accidents etc.). Currently we are reading the OBD parameters speed, temperature, rpm etc. Is it possible to identify the vehicle accidents scenario from these parameters or we need to use more parameter.

Please share your knowledge thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this in any way a programming question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can check for the sudden deviation in speed. We can get the speed and rpm information from the vehicle.